# how to filx Unexpected character (at char 1) in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

hy we have a radio server with the followoing json file

```
{
  "icestats":{
    "admin":"icemaster@localhost",
    "host":"online.localhost.be",
    "location":"Earth",
    "server_id":"Icecast 2.4.4",
    "server_start":"Sun, 30 Aug 2020 10:50:52 +0200",
    "server_start_iso8601":"2020-08-30T10:50:52+0200",
    "source":[
      {
        "audio_info":"ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=320;ice-channels=2",
        "bitrate":320,
        "genre":"oldies",
        "ice-bitrate":320,
        "ice-channels":2,
        "ice-samplerate":44100,
        "listener_peak":0,
        "listeners":0,
        "listenurl":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/mp3_320",
        "server_description":"Very Oldies!",
        "server_name":"loclahost",
        "server_type":"audio/mpeg",
        "server_url":"https://127.0.0.1:8000",
        "stream_start":"Sun, 30 Aug 2020 13:45:16 +0200",
        "stream_start_iso8601":"2020-08-30T13:45:16+0200",
        "title":"1951: Four Knights - I Love The Sunshine Of Your Smile",
        "dummy":null
      },
      {
        "audio_bitrate":320000,
        "audio_channels":2,
        "audio_info":"ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=320;ice-channels=2",
        "audio_samplerate":44100,
        "bitrate":320,
        "genre":"oldies",
        "ice-bitrate":320,
        "ice-channels":2,
        "ice-samplerate":44100,
        "listener_peak":0,
        "listeners":0,
        "listenurl":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/ogg_320",
        "server_description":"Very Oldies!",
        "server_name":"localhost",
        "server_type":"application/ogg",
        "server_url":"https://127.0.0.1:8000",
        "stream_start":"Sun, 30 Aug 2020 13:45:16 +0200",
        "stream_start_iso8601":"2020-08-30T13:45:16+0200",
        "subtype":"Vorbis",
        "dummy":null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if io parse this with this model i get the error 'unexpected charcater at 1'

```
class Autogenerated {
  Icestats icestats;

  Autogenerated({this.icestats});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    icestats = json['icestats'] != null
        ? new Icestats.fromJson(json['icestats'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.icestats != null) {
      data['icestats'] = this.icestats.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Icestats {
  String admin;
  String host;
  String location;
  String serverId;
  String serverStart;
  String serverStartIso8601;
  List<Source> source;

  Icestats(
      {this.admin,
        this.host,
        this.location,
        this.serverId,
        this.serverStart,
        this.serverStartIso8601,
        this.source});

  Icestats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    admin = json['admin'];
    host = json['host'];
    location = json['location'];
    serverId = json['server_id'];
    serverStart = json['server_start'];
    serverStartIso8601 = json['server_start_iso8601'];
    if (json['source'] != null) {
      source = new List<Source>();
      json['source'].forEach((v) {
        source.add(new Source.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['admin'] = this.admin;
    data['host'] = this.host;
    data['location'] = this.location;
    data['server_id'] = this.serverId;
    data['server_start'] = this.serverStart;
    data['server_start_iso8601'] = this.serverStartIso8601;
    if (this.source != null) {
      data['source'] = this.source.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String audioInfo;
  int bitrate;
  String genre;
  int iceBitrate;
  int iceChannels;
  int iceSamplerate;
  int listenerPeak;
  int listeners;
  String listenurl;
  String serverDescription;
  String serverName;
  String serverType;
  String serverUrl;
  String streamStart;
  String streamStartIso8601;
  String title;
  Null dummy;
  int audioBitrate;
  int audioChannels;
  int audioSamplerate;
  String subtype;

  Source(
      {this.audioInfo,
        this.bitrate,
        this.genre,
        this.iceBitrate,
        this.iceChannels,
        this.iceSamplerate,
        this.listenerPeak,
        this.listeners,
        this.listenurl,
        this.serverDescription,
        this.serverName,
        this.serverType,
        this.serverUrl,
        this.streamStart,
        this.streamStartIso8601,
        this.title,
        this.dummy,
        this.audioBitrate,
        this.audioChannels,
        this.audioSamplerate,
        this.subtype});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    audioInfo = json['audio_info'];
    bitrate = json['bitrate'];
    genre = json['genre'];
    iceBitrate = json['ice-bitrate'];
    iceChannels = json['ice-channels'];
    iceSamplerate = json['ice-samplerate'];
    listenerPeak = json['listener_peak'];
    listeners = json['listeners'];
    listenurl = json['listenurl'];
    serverDescription = json['server_description'];
    serverName = json['server_name'];
    serverType = json['server_type'];
    serverUrl = json['server_url'];
    streamStart = json['stream_start'];
    streamStartIso8601 = json['stream_start_iso8601'];
    title = json['title'];
    dummy = json['dummy'];
    audioBitrate = json['audio_bitrate'];
    audioChannels = json['audio_channels'];
    audioSamplerate = json['audio_samplerate'];
    subtype = json['subtype'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['audio_info'] = this.audioInfo;
    data['bitrate'] = this.bitrate;
    data['genre'] = this.genre;
    data['ice-bitrate'] = this.iceBitrate;
    data['ice-channels'] = this.iceChannels;
    data['ice-samplerate'] = this.iceSamplerate;
    data['listener_peak'] = this.listenerPeak;
    data['listeners'] = this.listeners;
    data['listenurl'] = this.listenurl;
    data['server_description'] = this.serverDescription;
    data['server_name'] = this.serverName;
    data['server_type'] = this.serverType;
    data['server_url'] = this.serverUrl;
    data['stream_start'] = this.streamStart;
    data['stream_start_iso8601'] = this.streamStartIso8601;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['dummy'] = this.dummy;
    data['audio_bitrate'] = this.audioBitrate;
    data['audio_channels'] = this.audioChannels;
    data['audio_samplerate'] = this.audioSamplerate;
    data['subtype'] = this.subtype;
    return data;
  }
}
```

the code i have used i pretty simple this is the code i have used.
if i parse the same code with a simple xml structure this works but with the icecast parsing this does not succeed.

please advice me

```
var JsonData = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/status-json.xsl';
var parsedJson = json.decode(JsonData);
var title = Source.fromJson(parsedJson);
```

is the json formatting of the icecast server incorrect ? it starts with a {

**update 1**

```
class User {
  String title;

  User(Map<String, dynamic> data){
    title = data['title'];

  }
}
Future<Source> fetchData() async{
  var jsonData = 'http://online.doobeedoo.be:8000/status-json.xsl';
  final response =
      await http.get(jsonData); //wacht to de data is ontvangen (200)
  if(response.statusCode == 200)
  {
    var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body); //parsen van response
    var user = User(parsedJson);
    return('${user.title}'); //error here (A value of type 'String' can't be returned from function 'fetchData' because it has a return type of 'Future<Source>'.)
  }
  else
    {
      throw Exception('Failed to load status.json response file');
    }
}
```

Comment: the key i call is source:title

Comment: You're trying to parse `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/status-json.xsl'`, which is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Can't I parse a remote json?

Comment: You have to obtain the JSON, which your code does not do. But right now you're parsing `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/status-json.xsl'`.

Comment: You mean the response you get is the one you provided above (the contents of the json file you mentioned)?

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjona They're not getting any response. They're trying to parse the URL as a JSON.

Comment: I get it. You just tried to parse the url there. You must get a response from an http request to get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to make a request to your server and retrieve a response. Then parse the JSON the way your currently have it. You're currently parsing a `String` URL. Not a JSON.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/status-json.xsl';

var response = await http.get(url);//Actually get the data at the URL

var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);//Parse the response
var title = Source.fromJson(parsedJson);
```

Comment: if i do this i get this error ```A value of type 'String' can't be returned from function 'fetchData' because it has a return type of 'Future<Source>'.``` i will update to code above to what i changed

Comment: @AlainSeys Because you completely neglected to use your own `fromJson` constructor. The error is quite clear about the issue. You should be explaining what you don't understand about the issue, not expect code to be written just to fix it for you.

Comment: what i get about the error is that string cant be assigned inside the function fetchData while i have set String title in my user class so if i call : user.title this should result the data ?

Comment: @Alain you need to clarify that last statement

Comment: whell in my user class i reference the title i would expect i should be able to call user.title that would result in the output of my json file with the song title.

Comment: @AlainSeys The issue is not with `user.title`. The return type of the surrounding function is not compatible with what you're trying to return.

Comment: what would a valid return type then be ?

Comment: @AlainSeys `Future<String>`

Comment: @AlainSeys Have you fixed the issue

Comment: Hy Christopher the String is resolved now i am looking why it does not print anything out

Comment: @AlainSeys If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept it. If not, provide more detail as to why it does not.

Comment: Hy Christopher the issue with the string is resolved  by adding Future<String> solved my issue now i am able to cal this information.